# Dotnetbar componnet is not working after reinstalled window

Tags: dotnetbar

I'm using visual studio 2010. I have used dotnetbar for windows forms (version 9.0.0) controls in my project. They all were working fine.

I have reinstalled windows and after reinstalling, Dontnetbar Controls are not showing in designer view. All built-in components are working properly.

Comment: Welcome at SO. I really suggest to read the tour, which will also help you to see the reason of the edit.

Comment: @D.Noori Please add more details to your question, such as any errors that appear or steps to recreate.

Comment: I created a c# app just to test the DotNetBar components it works perfectly in my computer but when i sent it to a friend to tried the app crashes instantly. do I have to move some dll files or something. thanks